# Searching strings through log with Python 3.8

Tags: search, filter, python-3.8

I am making some sort of script which would return lines from log file. Having issue with printing out lines which does not suite requested conditions.

Leaving example of log file:

```
2021-05-14 04:16:22,164 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:22,215 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,311 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,312 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,620 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,750 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><objectError>Error_Data</objectError>
&QADQ;requestID = &Qot;'r#qwsrdq'/version=.../object=.../...
END OF QUERY <response><info><error></error></info></response>
2021-05-14 05:23:11,140 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueB</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 05:23:11,431 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueB</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,266 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'
<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<value>Data</value>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,315 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'
```

So basic idea is to get lines with ID_valueA, but also I need all the other data blocks which are connected with ID_valueA. So expected result would be:

```
2021-05-14 04:16:22,164 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:22,215 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,311 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,312 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,620 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,750 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><objectError>Error_Data</objectError>
&QADQ;requestID = &Qot;'r#qwsrdq'/version=.../object=.../...
END OF QUERY <response><info><error></error></info></response>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,266 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '12355557'
<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<value>Data</value>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,315 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '12355557'
```

For now I have managed to result:

```
2021-05-14 04:16:22,164 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:22,215 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,311 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,312 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,620 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,750 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><objectError>Error_Data</objectError>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,266 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '12355557'
<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<value>Data</value>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,315 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '12355557'
**
&QADQ;requestID = &Qot;'r#qwsrdq'/version=.../object=.../...
END OF QUERY <response><info><error></error></info></response>
** 
         ^
     MISSING
```

I have used below code:

```
from file_manager import open_log_file
request_id = re.compile(r"requestID=\"[0-9a-zA-Z:-]+\"")
list_of_input_values = []
list_of_output_values = []
filename = []
id_list= []
case1="typeofRequest1"
case2="typeofResponse1"
case3="typeofRequest2"
case4="typeofResponse2"
case5="typeofRequest3"
case6="typeofResponse3"

status = True
while status == True:
    used = input('>>> ')
    if used.lower() == 'stop':
        break
    if used.lower() == 'ID_parameter1':
        ID_parameter1 = input('Please input ID_parameter1: ')
        list_of_input_values.insert(0,ID_parameter1)
        continue
    if used.lower() == 'ID_parameter2':
        ID_parameter2 = input('Please input ID_parameter2: ')
        list_of_input_values.insert(1,ID_parameter2)
        continue
    if used.lower() == 'ID_parameter3':
        ID_parameter3 = input('Please input ID_parameter3: ')
        list_of_input_values.insert(2,ID_parameter3)
        continue
    if used.lower() == '':
        continue
    if used.lower() == 'open':
        filename = open_log_file()

for element in filename:
    with open(element) as log:
        for line in log:
            for val in list_of_input_values:
                if val in line:
                    result = request_id.findall(line)
                    for i in result: 
                        id_list.append(i)

for element in filename:
    with open(element) as log:
        for line in log:
            for i in id_list:
                if i in line:
                    list_of_output_values.append(line)
                    for line in log:
                        if i in line:
                            list_of_output_values.append(line)
                        else:
                            if line.__contains__(case1 or case2 or case3 or case4 or case5 or case6 or case7 or case8):
                                break
                            else:
                                list_of_output_values.append(line)
                           


print(list_of_output_values, file=open(r'output\output.txt', "a"))
```

**from file_manager import open_log_file** :

```
def open_log_file():
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import fileinput
    unused_value = ">>> Unexpected input value: None. "
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    root.update()
    root.wm_iconbitmap(r'resources\myicon.ico')
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)
    filename = root.tk.splitlist(filename)
    filePath = []
    for f in filename:
        filePath.append(f)
    if filename == ():
        print(unused_value)
    return filePath
```

Can you please look around to understand what is wrong. I am expecting current loop to work well, but it seems not working that good. Searching is based on request ID parameter, because not every line contains ID_value specific parameter. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morning guys.

Can not explain why, maybe after taking a look of solution someone would give some decisions.
I have used:

```
print(list_of_output_values, file=open(r'output\output.txt', "a"))
```

At the end of code. Which gave me following output:

```
2021-05-14 04:16:22,164 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:22,215 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,311 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,312 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,620 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,750 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><objectError>Error_Data</objectError>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,266 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '12355557'
<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<value>Data</value>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,315 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '12355557'
```

Now scrolling down the code, I have decided to change print() function to write() block for clearer output. and using:

```
with open(r'output\output.txt', "a") as file:
   for i in list_of_output_values:
      file.write(i)
```

And now I am getting:

```
2021-05-14 04:16:22,164 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:22,215 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '1234xz987'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,311 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:16:23,312 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'abcd672'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,620 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><object>Data</object>
2021-05-14 04:17:24,750 instanceA 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = 'r#qwsrdq'<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier><objectError>Error_Data</objectError>
&QADQ;requestID = &Qot;'r#qwsrdq'/version=.../object=.../...
END OF QUERY <response><info><error></error></info></response>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,266 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <request>requestID = '12355557'
<identifier>ID_valueA</identifier>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<object>Data</object>
<value>Data</value>
2021-05-14 06:34:12,315 instanceA - WEB_GUI 10.0.0.1 <response>responseID = '12355557'
```